# Reemplazar valores en celdas de una matriz a partir de otra

Tags: python, matrices, bucles, numpy

He creado una matriz de ceros de 18x18 llamada ‘**master_matrix**’, lo que busco es reemplazar los valores de sus filas y columnas, en sus índices correspondientes con los valores que me da otra matriz de 6x6 llamada ‘**little_matrix**’.

Para ello he creado una función llamada ‘**reemplaza_master**’ que reemplaza esos ceros por los valores de ‘**little_matrix**’ encasillándolos donde los índices indiquen.

Este proceso lo tengo que repetir 6 veces con otros índices, para que esto suceda he creado una matriz llamada ‘**ingreso_datos**’ y un bucle que me permitirá hacer ese proceso para los 6 elementos que están ahí.

**PROBLEMA**

Mi problema está en que todo esto funciona bien sólo si mis tres primeros índices i se conectan de forma consecutiva con sus tres siguientes índices j, por ejemplo, en el elemento 6 de la matriz ‘**ingreso_datos**’, mis índices i son (1,2,3) y sus respectivos índices j son (4,5,6). PERO, si no se conectan de forma consecutiva, como lo que sucede en el elemento 4 cuyos índices i son (10,11,12) y sus respectivos j se saltan a (4,5,6), ahí YA NO funciona y se desordena todo. Adjunto imágenes:

-Esta matriz corresponde al elemento 6 y ahí si me sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Pero esta matriz que corresponde al elemento 4 ya no me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comentado el elemento 5 y 6 de la matriz ‘**ingreso_datos**’ para que observen lo que me sale del elemento 4, si quieren ver lo que sale con el elemento 6 cuyos índices son consecutivos le pueden quitar el comentario.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar y si tienen alguna duda pueden escribir, estaré muy atento, saludos.

```
import numpy as np

# 1 Defino la matriz de ceros grande en donde luego ubicaré los valores en función de la 'little_matrix'__________________________________

master_matrix = np.zeros((18,18))

# 2. Definir función que permita ubicar los valores de 'little_matrix' a 'master_matrix' !!!!_____________________________________________

def reemplaza_master(indice_i, valor_i):
    l = 0
    datos_a = []
    datos_a.extend(little_matrix[indice_i]) #--> Obtener datos fila 0 de la 'little_matrix'
    for d in datos_a:
        master_matrix[valor_i][pivot_indice + l] = d #--> Escribir en la 'master_matrix'
        l += 1

# 3. Datos ingresados por interfaz de usuario_____________________________________________________________________________________________

#              Fila de     |---------INDICES: Los indices definen posición donde los ceros de 'master_matrix' son reemplazados por valores de 'little_matrix'----|
#              Elemento    |-------1(i)            2(i)            3(i)             1(j)           2(j)                 3(j) -----------------------------------|
#               [Col0]     |------[Col1]          [Col2]          [Col3]           [Col4]         [Col5]               [Col6] ----------------------------------|

ingreso_datos = [[ 1,              13,            14,               15,               7,             8,                  9],
                 [ 2,              16,            17,               18,              10,            11,                12],
                 [ 3,               7,             8,                9,               1,             2,                 3],
                 [ 4,              10,            11,               12,               4,             5,                 6]]
#                 [ 5,               7,             8,                9,              10,            11,                 12],
#                 [ 6,               1,             2,                3,               4,             5,                    6]]

# 4. Bucle que permitirá trabajar con cada fila de cada elemento__________________________________________________________________________

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)): #--> Para cada fila en el rango de 'ingreso de datos'[i]...

    indices = [] #--> Extraigo los índices para cada elemento, dentro del bucle i 
    indices.extend([ingreso_datos[i][1], ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3],
                    ingreso_datos[i][4], ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6]])   

    indices_ensamble = [] #--> Debido a que la matriz se cuenta desde cero, a la lista de índices le tuve que restar 1 
    for e in indices:
        indices_ensamble.append(e-1)

# 4. Extracción de variables que posee cada elemento para cálculo de 'little_matrix'_____________________________________________________

    d = 5
    s = 0.2          
    e = 0.05            
    y = 5000000           

# 5. Cálculo de 'little_matrix'__________________________________________________________________________________________________________     

#                            |---INDICES: Son los indices de 'little_matrix' que reemplazarán a los de 'master_matrix'----| 
#                            |---1(i)        2(i)         3(i)        1(j)         2(j)         3(j) ---------------------|
    little_matrix = np.array([[ s*y/d,           0,           0,    -s*y/d,            0,           0],
                              [     0,    y*e/d**3,    y*e/d**2,         0,    -y*e/d**3,    y*e/d**2],
                              [     0,    y*e/d**2,       y*e/d,         0,    -y*e/d**2,       y*e/d],
                              [-s*y/d,           0,           0,     s*y/d,            0,           0],
                              [     0,    y*e/d**3,   -y*e/d**2,         0,     y*e/d**3,   -y*e/d**2],
                              [     0,    y*e/d**2,       y*e/d,         0,    -y*e/d**2,       y*e/d]])

# 6. Ensamblaje de la 'master_matrix'___________________________________________________________________________________________________

for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):

    pivot_indice = indices_ensamble[0] #--> Índice Pivot: Es el índice que ubica el primer elemento de 'little_matrix', para luego insertar en 'master_matrix' 
    for indice_i, valor_i in enumerate(indices_ensamble): #--> Para cada fila en el rango de 'indices'...
        reemplaza_master(indice_i, valor_i) #--> Reemplazar matriz de ceros en 'master_matrix' por los lugares correspondientes de la 'little_matrix' en función de los índices
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estás complicando demasiado y desaprovechando la potencialidad de NumPy a la hora de indizar y asignar nuevos valores a través de la vista de forma eficiente. Para asignar la matriz `little_matrix` al lugar correspondiente basta con hacer:

```
master_matrix[np.ix_(indices, indices)] = little_matrix
```

dónde `indices` son los seis indices obtenidos desde cada fila de la matriz `ingreso_datos` menos 1 para adaptarlos al indizado base 0, (`[9, 10, 11, 3, 4, 5]` para la fila 4)

```
import numpy as np


master_matrix = np.zeros((18, 18))

ingreso_datos = [[4, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6]]


for row in ingreso_datos:
    ind = np.array(row[1:])
    ind -= 1

    d = 5
    s = 0.2          
    e = 0.05            
    y = 5000000           


    little_matrix = np.array(
        [[ s*y/d,           0,           0,    -s*y/d,            0,           0],
         [     0,    y*e/d**3,    y*e/d**2,         0,    -y*e/d**3,    y*e/d**2],
         [     0,    y*e/d**2,       y*e/d,         0,    -y*e/d**2,       y*e/d],
         [-s*y/d,           0,           0,     s*y/d,            0,           0],
         [     0,    y*e/d**3,   -y*e/d**2,         0,     y*e/d**3,   -y*e/d**2],
         [     0,    y*e/d**2,       y*e/d,         0,    -y*e/d**2,       y*e/d]]
         )


    master_matrix[np.ix_(ind, ind)] = little_matrix
```

La salida es:

```
>>> master_matrix

[[      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.  200000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0. -200000.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.    2000.  -10000.       0.       0.        0.       0.    2000.  -10000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.  -10000.   50000.       0.       0.        0.       0.   10000.   50000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0. -200000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.  200000.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.   -2000.   10000.       0.       0.        0.       0.    2000.   10000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.  -10000.   50000.       0.       0.        0.       0.   10000.   50000.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]
 [      0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.        0.       0.]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y por tu tiempo, y sí, tienes mucha razón, me he estado complicando bastante, esta solución era justo lo que buscaba. Saludos cordiales y éxitos.